# Jquery 1.4.2 IE - ajax "Expected ;" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have autocomplete, that simply calls $.ajax. And when its getting result, it tries to evaluate with globalEval function. That making

```
<script>
   {"success": true}
</script>
```

Than IE says "Expected ;". Near I have another ajax call that is working good and without globalEval executing. What can cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` call?